# Inject settings in Setup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

On Application_Start of a MVC project, using Autofac, I have the following:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
  protected void Application_Start() {
    RouteSetup.Run();
  } // Application_Start
}
```

RouteSetup is as follows:

```
public class RouteSetup {

  public static void Run() {

    ISettings settings = new Settings();

    RouteTable.Routes.Localization(x => {
      x.AcceptedCultures = settings.AcceptedLanguages;
      x.DefaultCulture = settings.DefaultLanguage;
    });

    CultureSensitiveHttpModule.GetCultureFromHttpContextDelegate = context => { return new CultureResolver().GetCulture(context); };

  } // Run
}
```

ISettings is a class I inject in various parts of my application.

How should I request this class in RouteSetup?

Comment: Add it as a parameter to the `RouteSetup` constructor? (If `RouteSetup` is never constructed, then why is it not a static class?)

Comment: @MatthewWatson there isn't a way to get that since `Run` is static.

Comment: I can make Run a non static method ... But I think it should since it is a setup class ... But I am open to suggestions ....

Comment: Well since only default language is used, why not make that a parameter to Run()?

Comment: DefaultCulture, AccepetedCultures and other settings which I omitted for sake of simplicity ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `Run` method to accept a `ILifetimeScope` (`IContainer` inherits from `ILifetimeScope`) or you can use the `DependencyResolver` provided by ASP.net MVC, in the second case the ASP.net `DependencyResolver` has to be configured using `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(...)`

```
public class RouteSetup {

  public static void Run(ILifetimeScope scope) {

    ISettings settings = scope.Resolve<ISettings>();
    // or 
    ISettings settings = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISettings>();

    RouteTable.Routes.Localization(x => {
      x.AcceptedCultures = settings.AcceptedLanguages;
      x.DefaultCulture = settings.DefaultLanguage;
    });

    CultureSensitiveHttpModule.GetCultureFromHttpContextDelegate = context => { 
      return new CultureResolver().GetCulture(context); 
    };

  } // Run
}
```

By the way, I recommend you trying to always inject dependency using constructor parameter.

Comment: Yes, I agree that injecting into the constructor it is the best option ... But what how would you do it in this case? Remove static from Run method?

Comment: Why injecting ILifetimeScope instead of IContainer? And how would you create call RouteSetup in application start? Just create a new instance of ILifetimeScope?

Comment: As I said, `ILifetimeScope` is the base interface of `IContainer` so you can send your container to the `Run` method (ie : `RouteSetup.Run(container)`). I use `ILifetimeScope` instead of `IContainer` because you only need methods that are available on this type